# How to find temporal derivative of a set of values?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have set of 14 values(eg.. 15,122,231,etc..).These values change for a time interval T.Now is it possible to find temporal derivative of all values in that set?

Comment: This isn't clear.  Are you saying that you have a function of time, $f(t)$ such that $f(0)=15,f(1)=122,f(2)=231, \cdots$?  If so, you can compute the discrete derivative $\Delta f(t)=f(t+1)-f(t)$, but that's it.  If you know more values you can get a better approximation of the continuous derivative.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @lulu at time t i have set(15,122,231,etc..),at time t+1 that set changed to (20,148,259,etc..).after certain time T.Is it possible to find time derivative of all values in that set?

Comment: So, this is a vector valued function of time?  Again...you can compute $\frac 1T\left(f(t+T)-f(t)\right)$ to get a discrete, vector valued derivative.  Not sure what you are looking for, though.

Comment: Do you have a set or an ordered list?

Comment: @lulu thats it.Thank you